# which file in ubuntu defines meaning of each run level?

Tags: init, init.d, runlevel

In redhat based linux, there is a file called **inittab** in which you can see the meaning and definition of each run level. Is there any file like this in Ubuntu?

I know what each run level means in Debian based linuxes. I know about rc#.d files and also config files inside init folder. I just need to know **if there is an alternative for inittab in ubuntu or not.** googling didnt do any good.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Alternative in ubuntu for inittab is `/etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf`
You can edit `/etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf`
and change the following line:

```
env DEFAULT_RUNLEVEL=N
```

Where N is the default runlevel, change this to match.

Comment: thank you very much. But then again this file only defines the default run level, and it's not introducing the other run levels.